# How to build last version of Ruby for jailbroken iOS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia, ruby

I jailbrake my iPad and want to run Ruby in the console. I installed OpenSSH & Ruby from Saurik. But it is too old (1.9.2) & buggy.

I would like to compile and install the latest version of Ruby on my iPad. Help me, how to do this?

Comment: Not to dishearten you, but if there is no newer version compiled, it's probably for good reason. Porting something as large as Ruby to iOS isn't exactly easy. Depending on what you are doing this may be of interest: http://www.rubymotion.com/.

Comment: Assuming you have build tools working, why not download the Ruby source, `./configure`, `make`, and see what errors pop up? iOS devices are tiny Macs anyway. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

If you have `OpenSSH`, you may want to connect via SSH to a Unix based computer and run a full version of Ruby. For Mac there is [MacRuby](http://macruby.org/), for Linux just install Ruby via your package manager.